Integrating OpenLayers in Yew with Rust: Module specifier error
I am quite new to Yew.
I've built a webpage using Rocket + Tera, and it works well, but I somehow feel it's gonna be better to make the front end with Yew, also because I want to learn it. Everything went smoothly till I had to integrate the page that uses OpenLayers and shows a map...
Specifically, I am encountering a module specifier error when attempting to load a JavaScript file. Below is the relevant part of my Rust code where I use wasm_bindgen to interface with JavaScript.
map.rs
use wasm_bindgen::prelude::*;
use yew::prelude::*;

#[wasm_bindgen(module = "js/ol_setup.js")]
extern "C" {
    fn setupMap();
}

pub struct MapComponent;

impl Component for MapComponent {
    type Message = ();
    type Properties = ();

    fn create(_ctx: &Context<Self>) -> Self {
        Self
    }

    fn view(&self, _ctx: &Context<Self>) -> Html {
        html! {
            <div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 400px;"></div>
        }
    }

    fn rendered(&mut self, _ctx: &Context<Self>, first_render: bool) {
        if first_render {
            setupMap();
        }
    }
}

Here is the js file
import Map from 'ol/Map';
import View from 'ol/View';
import TileLayer from 'ol/layer/Tile';
import OSM from 'ol/source/OSM';
import { fromLonLat } from 'ol/proj';

export function setupMap() {
    const map = new Map({
        target: 'map',
        layers: [
            new TileLayer({
                source: new OSM()
            })
        ],
        view: new View({
            center: fromLonLat([2.5394715837505943, 41.61142827651791]),
            zoom: 15
        })
    });
    console.log("Map loaded");
}

When I run the application, the JavaScript console throws the following error:
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "js/ol_setup.js". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".

The file ol_setup.js is part of my project structure and is located under static/js. My index.html is set up as follows:
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>App title</title>
    <link data-trunk rel="scss" href="static/css/main.scss"/>
    <link data-trunk rel="copy-dir" href="static/img"/>
    <link data-trunk rel="copy-dir" href="static/js"/>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>

I suspect the issue might be related to how the module path is resolved in the wasm_bindgen attribute. Somehow, it is not able to load it when it is moved to the folder dist. How should I correctly specify the path to ensure the JavaScript file is properly loaded? Also, is there a specific setup or configuration in Yew or Trunk that I might be missing to handle external JS files correctly?
I am actually trying a workaround that consists of just importing the js module from the div, like this:
use yew::{Component, Context, html, Html};

pub struct MapComponent; // Any struct that implements Component is a component

impl Component for MapComponent {
    type Message = ();
    type Properties = ();

    fn create(_ctx: &Context<Self>) -> Self {
        Self
    }

    fn view(&self, _ctx: &Context<Self>) -> Html {
        html! {
            <>
            <div id="map"></div>
            <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/ol@latest/dist/ol.js"></script>
            <script src="ol_setup.js"></script>
            </>
        }
    }
}

However, it does not work. It always fails in the first line of the code when trying to import the import Map from 'ol/Map';
Then I tried to download the package and move it to dist, adding this line to my index:
<link data-trunk rel="copy-dir" href="node_modules/ol"/>
But it also does not work, although I can do 127.0.0.1/ol/Map.js.
Does anyone have a clue on how to do this?

Well, It looks like it is harder than I expected. If you want to use openlayers, you cannot just convert your JS code, you have to convert the whole module.
I've moved to leaflet instead of Open Layers since there is already a crate for it leaflet-rs. It includes modules for Yew even. So, great.
